# Can I read smartphone batteries gas gauge info with a PIC?

Tags: pic, batteries, gauge

I'm in a quest trying to find some easy way of having my batteries charge level displayed. I've found it not so trivial as I thought it would be (because any smartphone is capable of doing that). Than it hits me, it must be something to do with theirs batteries.

I've learned some models of battery have one or two terminals for communication to an gas gauge integrated inside the battery package.

So the question is, are those terminals easy to be read? If I decide to use that kind of battery in my project, can I read that gas gauge with a PIC? What kind of protocols are used normally for that communication? Do OEMs give that kind of info?

Does anyone knows where to find that? Any datasheet. I could not find anything actually on the web.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an excerpt from an [article](http://www.maxim-ic.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3958) I found:

> "To determine the available charge in a battery, simple monitoring methods are preferred. They should consume little energy and should (ideally) allow one to deduce the charge level from battery voltage. Such a voltage-only method can produce unreliable outcomes, however, because no clear correlation exists between voltage and the available charge (Figure 5). Battery voltage also depends on temperature, and dynamic relaxation effects can cause a slow increase in the terminal voltage after a reduction in load current. Thus, purely voltage-based monitoring is unlikely to provide charge-level accuracies better than 25%.
>
> The relative charge level, often called the state of charge (SOC), is defined as the ratio of residual charge to the battery's charge capacity. Hence charge flow must be measured and monitored through a procedure called "coulomb counting." In practice, coulomb counting is accomplished by integrating the currents flowing into and out of the cell. To measure these currents with a high-resolution ADC, one typically connects a small resistor in series with the anode."

Here is a [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8078.pdf) I found for an Atmel AVR352 that you could use for coulomb counting:

Even better would be to refer [here](http://www.reuk.co.uk/Measuring-the-Capacity-of-a-Battery.htm).

And there are [devices](http://www.ti.com/product/bq27000).

Though as far as I can see there is plenty of info on the web; i don't see how you could have missed it.

Comment: Many rechargeable battery packs today contain built-in gas-gauge devices; among other things, this means that if one removes one battery and inserts another, the device receiving the new battery can instantly know its state of charge.  I think the question had to do with whether there was any easy-to-use standard for such devices.

Answer (score 1):

There's an old saying, "the wonderful thing about standards is that there are so many of them".  There are many ways one can design a battery pack with integrated electronics; different approaches have different trade-offs with regard to battery-pack cost, reliance on end-user-device cooperation, measurement accuracy, quiescent current for uninstalled battery packs, etc.  I would expect that there are some battery packs whose status may be queried fairly easily, but even if you find a battery pack that seems absolutely perfect there's no guarantee that exact model will be easy to find next year.

It's worth noting that some integrated-electronics battery packs include all the circuitry necessary to keep track of what goes into and comes out of the battery.  A device that wishes to use such a pack can draw current as it sees fit (within limits), and at any time ask the battery pack how much current remains.  Circuitry to measure incoming and outgoing charge is not free, however.  An alternative approach is to simply include a non-volatile memory within the battery pack, and have the end-user device use its own charge-management circuitry to update the non-volatile information stored in the pack.  Using battery packs that are designed in such fashion would likely be somewhat problematic.  Even if your application didn't need to know the charge state, a phone might get confused if you plugged in a battery that had been drained elsewhere without updating its battery-management info.

Answer (score 1):

> If I decide to use that kind of battery in my project, can I read that
>   gas gauge with a PIC? What kind of protocols are used normally for
>   that communication? Do OEMs give that kind of info?

I've bought Li-ion batteries from an OEM called Rose Electronics.  They told me which gas gauge ICs they put into their batteries.  Those happened to be [bq27000 (1-wire interface)](http://www.ti.com/product/bq27000) or [bq27200 (I<sup>2</sup>C interface)](http://www.ti.com/product/bq27200), depending on the battery pack model.  Those ICs have a lot in common and are described by the same datasheet.  The details of the communication protocol are in the datasheet.